# Having trouble with differentiating under integral sign

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I am sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but I am having trouble in applying differentiation under the integral sign to definite integrals such as this one:
$$\int^{1}_{0} x^p(\ln{x})^mdx=\frac{(-1)^mm!}{(p+1)^{m+1}}$$
This is what I have tried so far
$$I(p)=\int^{1}_{0} x^p(\ln{x})^mdx$$
$$I'(p)=\int^{1}_{0} x^p(\ln{x})^{m+1}dx=-\frac{m+1}{p+1}\int^{1}_{0} x^p(\ln{x})^mdx=-\frac{m+1}{p+1}I(p)$$
and this is where I get stuck. I would really need help in understanding how to apply this technique. Assistance offered would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the only problem in this case is that it's not obvious that your two answers are equivalent. Try calculating the ratio $I'(p)/I(p)$ using both results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I(p)=\int_0^1 x^p\,dx=\frac{1}{p+1}$$
Differentiate with respect to $p\,$ $m$ times and you get your result.